# Possible to combine a pie.operator and box.operator together?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, pie-menu

Would it be possible to have pie operators along all 8 pie positions and below pie 2 have a column of box operators?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot have all 8 pie positions and another extra box.

You can have boxes instead some pie positions though. So you can have 7 pie positions and the bottom 8th one being a box:

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    pie = layout.menu_pie()
    #4 - LEFT
    pie.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", text="LEFT", icon='MESH_CUBE')
    #6 - RIGHT
    pie.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", text="RIGHT", icon='MESH_CUBE')
    #2 - BOTTOM
    box = pie.box().column()
    box.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", text="BOTTOM 1", icon='MESH_CUBE')
    box.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", text="BOTTOM 2", icon='MESH_CUBE')
    box.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", text="BOTTOM 3", icon='MESH_CUBE')
    box.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", text="BOTTOM 4", icon='MESH_CUBE')
    #8 - TOP
    pie.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", text="TOP", icon='MESH_CUBE')
    #7 - TOP - LEFT
    pie.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", text="TOP - LEFT", icon='MESH_CUBE')
    #9 - TOP - RIGHT
    pie.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", text="TOP - RIGHT", icon='MESH_CUBE')
    #1 - BOTTOM - LEFT
    pie.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", text="BOTTOM - LEFT", icon='MESH_CUBE')
    #3 - BOTTOM - RIGHT
    pie.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", text="BOTTOM - RIGHT", icon='MESH_CUBE')
```

You can split rows, create multiple columns, etc. Normal formatting methods of Blender UI applies. If you omit the `.box()` you don't have that ugly border and only grouped entries which looks better imho.

[image]